# Executing a scriptblock via startprocess

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, credentials, start-process

Would any of you possibly know why this is not working?

```
Start-Process $PSHOME\powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-NoExit -Command & `"{$outvar1 = 4+4; `"out: $outvar1`"}`"" -Wait
```

The ultimate purpose for this is so that i can run a script block as another user with the addition of the -Credential option. But i can not get this simple script block to work yet. 
Many thanks.
Chris.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `Invoke-Command` which can run a script block locally or remotely with specified credentials (see example 2 in its [help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347578.aspx))?

Comment: Hi, Well truth is that im having an error when executing the AutoSPInstaller script, at line 2056 AutoSPInstallerFunctions.ps1. Im trying to replicate what it does, the original line is ;   Start-Process $PSHOME\powershell.exe -Credential $FarmCredential -ArgumentList "-Command Start-Process $PSHOME\powershell.exe -ArgumentList `"'$ScriptFile'`" -Verb Runas" -Wait

Comment: where script file is the path and file name of a script that was generated earlier in the process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is somthing that is working:

```
PS C:\> Start-Process $PSHOME\powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command  `"&{`$outvar1 = 4+4; `"write-output `$outvar1`"}`"" -Wait
```

-ArgumentList is an array of strings
$outvar is interpreted so I use `$outvar

Comment: Great, and then to add some text before we just escape the special chars, now i understand. cheers Start-Process $PSHOME\powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command `"&{`$outvar1 = 4+4; `"write-output `"Hello:`"`$outvar1`"}`"" -Wait

Comment: FYI, I prefer to use `$p = Start-Process ... -PassThru; Wait-Process $p.id -Timeout xxx`.  Just in case the started process hangs, my script won't hang any longer than the specified timeout.