# How its possible, to run scriptblock with different credentials and runas?

Tags: powershell, credentials, runas, scriptblock

My script should load credentials an run code with elevation.
I try to include one scriptblock to another. And run Start-Process with different parameter sets.
I have error "This command cannot be run due to the error: The stub received bad data".

````
$ScriptBlock = {
 Param(
     [datetime] $Start = '04/25/2020 19:52:25',
     [datetime] $End = '04/25/2020 19:52:35',
     [string] $OutputXMLPath = 'C:\DATA\Projects\EventLogsAnalyzer\DATA\ScriptBlockOutput.xml',
     [string] $logFilePath = 'C:\DATA\Projects\EventLogsAnalyzer\LOGS\EventLogsAnalyzer.log'
)                 
$ScriptBlock = {
    Param(
     [datetime] $Start = '04/25/2020 19:52:25',
     [datetime] $End = '04/25/2020 19:52:35',
     [string] $OutputXMLPath = 'C:\DATA\Projects\EventLogsAnalyzer\DATA\ScriptBlockOutput.xml'
    ) 

    $Logs  =  Get-WinEvent -ListLog *
    $Res = @()        
    Foreach($Log in $Logs) {           
        $Log.LogName
        $Filter = @{
            LogName            = $Log.LogName
            StartTime          = $Start
            EndTime            = $End
        }
        $Res += Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable $Filter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }      
 } 

$Res = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -PassThru -Verb "RunAs"  -ArgumentList " -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass –NoProfile -Command & { $ScriptBlock }"

$Res

}

$User = Get-VarFromAESFile $Global:GlobalKey1 $Global:APP_SCRIPT_ADMIN_Login
$Pass = Get-VarFromAESFile $Global:GlobalKey1 $Global:APP_SCRIPT_ADMIN_Pass
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList (Get-VarToString $User), $Pass

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -PassThru -Credential $Credentials  -ArgumentList " -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass –NoProfile -Command & { $ScriptBlock }"```
````

Answer (score 0):

A similar discussion on Stackoverflow can be seen here:

> [Executing a scriptblock via startprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318903/executing-a-scriptblock-via-startprocess)

A comment with thinking about in the Q&A

> Any reason you're not using Invoke-Command which can run a script
>   block locally or remotely with specified credentials (see example 2 in
>   its help)?

See also as an association with the aforementioned:

> [All about PowerShell ScriptBlock](http://www.padisetty.com/2014/05/all-about-powershell-scriptblock.html)

The accepted answer:

> Here is something that is working:

```
Start-Process $PSHOME\powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command  `"&{`$outvar1 = 4+4; `"write-output `$outvar1`"}`"" -Wait
```

> -ArgumentList is an array of strings $outvar is interpreted so I use `$outvar

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can run start-process without problem. The problem is to run it with credential and runas.